# Apple's Preview prints in middle of page

Tags: preview, printing, defaults

Apple's Preview app always prints in the center of the page, rather than at top & left margins. This is true regardless of the scale (% size) an image is printed at. I'm hoping there's a way to change the default, rather than having to change a setting each time I print, though I haven't found a way to do that, either. Anyone know how this can be changed?